# JS: how can I select a child in event.target?

Tags: javascript

I have a nested megu menu like this:

```
<ul class="nav-wrap">
  <li class="main-nav">
     <a>m1</a>
     <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li></li>
        ...
        <li><ul>...</ul><li>
     </ul>
  <li>
  <li class="main-nav">
     <a>m1</a>
     <ul class="sub-nav"></ul>
  <li>
  <li class="main-nav">
     <a>m1</a>
     <ul class="sub-nav"></ul>
  <li>
  ...
</ul>
```

for each `main-nav`, I want hover `main-nav`, and add `.show` class in `.sub-nav` (its child).

how can I do that?

I try this:

```
var dropdownMenus = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.main-nav'));

var dropdownList = dropdownElementList.map(function (dropdownToggleEl) {

    dropdownToggleEl.onmouseover= function(e){
        e.target.children.querySelector('ul.sub-nav').classList.toggle('show');
    };

    dropdownToggleEl.onmouseleave= function(e){
        e.target.children.querySelector('ul.sub-nav').classList.toggle('show');
    };

});
```

But I get this error:

```
net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
Uncaught TypeError: e.target.children.querySelector is not a function at HTMLLIElement.dropdownToggleEl.onmouseover
```

Comment: remove `.children`. In the future you should be comfortable with `console.log()`ing data to understand what it is. A console.log would have showed you that children is an array, which doesn't have .querySelector on it.

Comment: Why are you doing this with JS? Just CSS: `.main-nav:hover>.sub-nav {display:block}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is code missing in multiple places in JS, HTML and CSS, I've added the missing pieces. Use `onmouseenter` instead of `onmouseover` as it always provides the same element on which you added the event listener for `e.target` while same is not true for onmouseover.

```js
let dropdownElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.main-nav'));

dropdownElementList.map(function (dropdownToggleEl) {

    dropdownToggleEl.onmouseenter= function(e){
      e.target.querySelector('ul.sub-nav').classList.remove('hide');
      e.target.querySelector('ul.sub-nav').classList.add('show');
    };

    dropdownToggleEl.onmouseleave= function(e){
     e.target.querySelector('ul.sub-nav').classList.remove('show');
     e.target.querySelector('ul.sub-nav').classList.add('hide');
    };

});
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-wrap">
  <li class="main-nav">
     <a>m111</a>
     <ul class="sub-nav hide">
        <li>m1.s11</li>
        <li>m1.s22</li>
        <li><ul>...</ul></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main-nav">
     <a>m122</a>
     <ul class="sub-nav hide">
        <li>m2.s11</li>
        <li>m2.s22</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main-nav">
     <a>m133</a>
     <ul class="sub-nav"></ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```